# I don't know how to make __slots__ work

Tags: python

How come this code runs for me?

```
class Foo():
    __slots__ = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.should_not_work = "or does it?"
        print "This code does not run,",self.should_not_work

Foo()
```

I thought **slots** worked as a restriction. I'm running Python 2.6.6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `__slots__` mechanism works for new-style classes. You should inherit from `object`.

Change the class declaration to

```
class Foo(object):
  # etc...
```

Answer (score 9):

`__slots__` provides a small optimisation of memory use because it can prevent a `__dict__` being allocated to store the instance's attributes. This may be useful if you have a very large number of instances.

The restriction you are talking about is mostly an accidental side effect of the way it is implemented. In particular it only stops creation of a `__dict__` if your class inherits from a base class that does not have a `__dict__` (such as `object`) and even then it won't stop `__dict__` being allocated in any subclasses unless they also define `__slots__`. It isn't intended as a security mechanism, so it is best not to try to use it as such.

All old-style classes get `__dict__` automatically, so `__slots__` has no effect. If you inherit from `object` you will get the effect you are looking for, but basically don't bother with `__slots__` until you know you have millions of instances and memory is an issue.